# How do you exit an application with a press of a specific key?

Tags: c#, exit

I'm doing a small c# application.

(Press 0 to end the program)

All I know is:
Console.ReadKey(); but that only works when you press ANY key.

But how do you exit an application with just 0?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to run the while loop to findout the key.
you have to compare with the what ever users enters the key.

```
 ConsoleKeyInfo info=  Console.ReadKey();
        if (info.KeyChar == 48)
            Environment.Exit(0);
        else
        { // do your things
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your program will run in a while loop. Read the entered word and check in if condition that whenever it is 0 or not. If it is 0 then let the program finish by breaking the loop otherwise use continue. Let me know if you have any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` loop :

```
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();

        while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.D0 && cki.Key != ConsoleKey.NumPad0)
        {
            cki = Console.ReadKey(true);

            // your code here
        }
```